# Forbid string & object concatenation

Tags: c#

I am converting a bunch of strings in an api into classes. I am using extensively the compiler to help me with this, since I can replace some types in core apis, and follow the type errors.

However, there is a frustrating source of bugs with this approach:

```
// linqpad snippet
void Main()
{
    var t = "yay : " + (new Foo());
    t.Dump(); // "yay: namespace.Foo" instead of compilation error
}

class Foo {
}
```

C# will happily add together a string and any user defined object. Is there a way to turn this into a warning or a compilation error?

I want a compilation error, because this data is ultimately shown to the user. If I miss one concatenation, the users will see class names in the application, which is not really a behavior I want.

Comment: There's no warning for writing silly code! :)

Comment: Why this must be warning or error?

Comment: @DavidG I am in a refactoring situation. I have 50+ classes communicating together. I want to replace some data represented by a string by some other data represented by a class. In classes using string concatenation, I want to use other form of combination. If the compiler doesn't help me, that means that I might miss something, and users will see irrelevant class names in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C# will happily add together a string and any user defined object. Is there a way to turn this into a warning or a compilation error?

Yes - if you're using Visual Studio 2015 or higher :)

You can use [Roslyn](http://roslyn.codeplex.com) to create your own code diagnostic / code fix, and I *believe* this lets you escalate the problem from being just a warning to being an error. You can then include this diagnostic in your continuous integration build.

Be careful how far you go with this though - I would normally try to handle this in code review rather than making it an outright error. Creating your own dialect of C# could be a slippery slope...

Note that in some cases, the code you've given could be entirely appropriate - if `Foo` overrides `ToString()` for example. Are you really *sure* you want to ban this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sure that I want to ban this for all classes inheriting some abstract class or implementing a given interface. I was hoping something simpler. Since we are using visual 2013 I will try to write an fxcop rule. I was hoping that an easier solution would exist :-(. Having such a default behavior instead of a `IRepresentable` interface seems crazy.

Comment: We are conducting reviews, but the "risk surface" is really big on this one.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (which may not be appropriate) would be to override the `ToString` method in your classes and make them throw an error. This wouldn't give you compile time errors, but would give a runtime exception:

```
public class Test
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Of course this would be no good if you are already overriding `ToString`. As an extra level you could decorate your override to indicate that the method is not to be used:

```
[Obsolete("Don't use this!")]
public override string ToString()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

While this would have no effect on the code you posted, you should get warnings anywhere you explicitly call `ToString`, for example this will give a compiler warning:

```
var s = (new Test()).ToString();
```

Comment: sadly this method doesn't generate a warning on `var s = "" + (new Test());`

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my answer, but it will generate runtime exceptions.